# Как сделать чтобы количество кнопок отображалось правильно и не изменялось когда прокручиваешь список?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть список, где каждый элемент представляет CardView с тремя кнопками.
Для отображения на экране используется Frament помещенный в ViewPager.
Кнопки отображаются от одной до трех в зависимости от полученных данных.

Проблема в том что количество отображаемых кнопок меняется произвольно при каждой прокрутке списка.(Например: В списке десять элементов. На трех из них должно отображаться две кнопки а на остальных по три кнопки. А отображаемое кол-во кнопок не соответствует извлеченным данным, данные извлекаются из List).

Не нужные кнопки я прячу так:

```
if (holder.ussdCmdObj.getStatus().equals("no")) {
    holder.btnStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Как сделать чтобы количество кнопок отображалось правильно и не изменялось когда прокручиваешь список?

```
public class MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<UssdCmdObj> ussdCmdObjList;
    private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<UssdCmdObj> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
        ussdCmdObjList = items;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.ussdCmdObj = ussdCmdObjList.get(position);
        holder.description.setText(ussdCmdObjList.get(position).getDescription());

        if (holder.ussdCmdObj.getStatus().equals("no")) {
            holder.btnStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (holder.ussdCmdObj.getCmd_on().equals("empty")) {
            holder.btnOn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (holder.ussdCmdObj.getCmd_off().equals("empty")) {
            holder.btnOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
                String ussd = holder.ussdCmdObj.getStatus() + encodedHash;
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "=== " + holder.ussdCmdObj.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)));
            }
        });
        holder.btnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
                String ussd = holder.ussdCmdObj.getCmd_on() + encodedHash;
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "=== " + holder.ussdCmdObj.getCmd_on(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)));
            }
        });
        holder.btnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
                String ussd = holder.ussdCmdObj.getCmd_off() + encodedHash;
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "=== " + holder.ussdCmdObj.getCmd_off(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)));
            }
        });

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (null != mListener) {
                    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                    mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.ussdCmdObj);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ussdCmdObjList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView description;
        public final Button btnStatus;
        public final Button btnOn;
        public final Button btnOff;

        public UssdCmdObj ussdCmdObj;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Description);
            btnStatus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_status);
            btnOn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_on);
            btnOff = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_off);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте к этим условиям добавить

```
if (holder.ussdCmdObj.getStatus().equals("no")) {
        holder.btnStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
       holder.btnStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Вопрос решен.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в том, что вы по условию убираете кнопки, но не возвращаете их. Попробуйте устанавливать видимость оных в обоих случаях.

```
holder.btnStatus.setVisibility((holder.ussdCmdObj.getStatus().equals("no")?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);

holder.btnOn.setVisibility((holder.ussdCmdObj.getCmd_on().equals("empty")?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);

holder.btnOff.setVisibility((holder.ussdCmdObj.getCmd_off().equals("empty"))?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
```